# Edit Instagram profile via API?

Tags: api, instagram

I've read thru the Instagram API and didn't see a way to change profile information (photo, bio, links etc) via the API. Is this possible in some other way?

Or a broader question, is the only way to edit a users profile information manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no official Instagram API to edit profile info, profile picture, upload/delete photos.

You have to use Instagram app to change profile information and upload photos.